# show that $(E_1+...+E_r)x=Ix$

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra

Let $A$ be an $n \times n$ symmetric matrix. Suppose $A$'s eigenvalues are $\lambda_1,...,\lambda_n$ (including possible repeated values). Suppose the corresponding orthonormal eigenvectors are $u_1,...,u_n$. Define $E_i=\sum^n_{i=1}u_iu_i^T$ Let $x \in \Bbb R^n$. Write $x=\sum^n_{i=1}x_iu_i$

Task:

By direct computation, using the definition of $E_i$, show that $(E_1+...+E_r)x=Ix$ for all $x$

What I tried:

Since $E_i=\sum^n_{i=1}u_iu_i^T \Rightarrow E_1=nu_1u_1^T$ and the other similar. So,

$$(E_1+...+E_r)x=(nu_1u_1^T+...+nu_ru_r^T)\sum_{i=1}^n x_iu_i=nu_1u_1^Tx_1u_1+nu_2u_2^Tx_2u_2+...+nu_ru_r^Tx_ru_r+x_{r+1}u_{r+1}+...+x_nu_n=nx_1u_1+nx_2u_2+...+nx_ru_r+x_{r+1}u_{r+1}+...+x_nu_n=n\sum^r_{i=1}x_iu_i+x_{r+1}u_{r+1}+...+x_nu_n$$

I can't seem to get the right answer, what am i doing wrong?

By the way are $u$'s vectors in $\Bbb R^n$?

Comment: I think there is confusion about the indices. In this definition $E_i$ doesn't depend on $i$, because $i$ is used as an index in the sum.

Comment: So what exactly did I do wrong @obareey

Comment: The definition itself doesn't make any sense. There could be a typo in the question.

Comment: The definition of $E_i$ can't be right. Did you mean $E_i=u_iu_i^T$?

Comment: @AngelaPretorius i don't know, that's what it's written as in the textbook